# a2ps on mac os x: a strange result

Tags: macos, shell, unix

After studying Unix fundamentals I installed a2ps on my system, running Mac OS Sierra.
I tried :

```
ls /usr/bin | pr -3 -t | a2ps -o ~/Desktop/ls.ps -L 66
```

but I have the result in the following image (I enclosed just the first page of the output).
[ls.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQzDP.jpg)

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The second page on the sheet is cut on the right part. A piece of page is missing.